# Display grid card elements continuously and evenly without white space

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, grid-layout

I am trying to evenly and continuously show the card elements of the same category inside the grid without starting a new line.

As you can see 110-02641AR is next to 110-02642AL but the space is bigger than for the rest of the elements. And for example, 128-02545R starts on a new line instead of continuing from next to 125-02028L.

[image: screenshot]

I tried all grid layout formatting like align and justify. I also tried removing the div.

```
<v-layout v-for="(parentKey,j) in filteredGroupedParts" :key="j">
    <div>
        <v-subheader class="partCatSub" row style="padding-top:15px">
            {{parentKey.group}}
            <a :name="parentKey.group"></a>
        </v-subheader>
        <v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
            <v-layout row wrap>
                <div v-for="(key,i) in parentKey.partGroups" :key="i">
                    <v-layout row wrap>
                        <v-flex shrink v-for="(key1,i1) in key.parts" :key="i1">
                            <v-card :class="[isActive?'selectedpart':'card']" @click="isActive=!isActive">
                                <v-card-title primary class="title" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                                    {{key1.interchangeNo}}
                                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                    Qty. {{key1.quantity}}
                                </v-card-title>
                                <v-card-title style="padding-top:7px;height:86px">{{key1.description}}</v-card-title>
                                <v-card-title style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top:0px;font-weight: bold">
                                    {{key1.soldLastThirtyDays}} (${{key1.avgPriceLastThirtyDays}}) |
                                    {{key1.soldLastSixtyDays}} (${{key1.avgPriceLastSixtyDays}}) |
                                    {{key1.soldLastNinetyDays}} (${{key1.avgPriceLastNinetyDays}})
                                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                    Lookups: {{key1.partActivityLastYear}}
                                </v-card-title>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                </div>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
    </div>
</v-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! In order to render 2 divs with v-for inside you have to replace the first div with template and it works.